# custom robocopy script in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I would like to move all .txt files present in a source directory (including .txt present in subfolders) to a destination directory.

For eg:
Source directory: `D:\OFFICE work\robtest\test1`

Above directory also contains many subfolders.

Destination directory: `D:\OFFICE work\robtest\test2`

I would like to move only .txt files in source dir to the above mentioned destination directory, in such a way that only 3 .txt files must be present per sub folder (includes random folder creation) in the destination directory.

Below is the code I tried, but PowerShell says

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax .(D:\OFFICE work\robtest\test1\testtest\testtest2\
>   New folder\test01112.txt\ ) is incorrect.

I am not sure why there is extra '/' after the above path in robocopy.

```cs
$fileperfolder = 3
$source = "D:\OFFICE work\robtest\test1";
$dest = "D:\OFFICE work\robtest\test2";
$folderName = [System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName();
$fileList = Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Filter *.txt -Recurse
Write-Host $fileList
$i = 0;
foreach ($file in $fileList) {
    $destiny = $dest + "\" + $folderName
    Write-Host $file.FullName;
    Write-Host $destiny;
    New-Item $destiny -Type Directory -Force
    robocopy $file.FullName $destiny /mov
    $i++;
    if ($i -eq $fileperfolder) {
        $folderName = [System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName();
        $i = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a special reason to use robocopy? Why not use Move-Item? Also, at which line does the error occur?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error (and the "directory" in the output) because `robocopy` expects two *folders* as the first and second argument, optionally followed by a list of filename specs, but you're providing the path to a *file* as the source.

From the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> ### Syntax
>
> ```
> robocopy <Source> <Destination> [<File>[ ...]] [<Options>]
> ```
>
> ### Parameters
>
> - `<Source>` Specifies the path to the source ***directory***.
> - `<Destination>` Specifies the path to the destination ***directory***.
> - `<File>` Specifies the file or files to be copied. You can use wildcard characters (`*` or `?`), if you want. If the `File` parameter is not specified, `*.*` is used as the default value.
> - `<Options>` Specifies options to be used with the `robocopy` command.

Since you're moving one file at a time and apparently don't want to maintain the directory structure I'd say `robocopy` isn't the right tool for what you're doing anyway.

Replace

```
robocopy $file.FullName $destiny /mov
```

with

```
Move-Item $file.FullName $destiny
```

and the code should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

robocopy $file.Directory $destiny $file /mov

solved this issue.